# what is whitespace when inspecting?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I'm having a weird issue with webpack for along time, the issue is the layout in Dev is slightly different than the build, while inspecting in Firefox i found that the difference is the white space, my question is what is white space as showing in the image below, and how to keep that white space after building ?

[image: whitespave]

Comment: Here's why this happens: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e7ksdxgc/ to keep the whitespace, you can put `&nbsp;` in between, or use margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace is a set of characters which is used to show horizontal or vertical spaces between other characters. They are often used to separate tokens in HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

To keep it ,  You can use this code &#8287 and add a space in the HTML content.